# Structuring information

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have a class that represents a person, with some information

```
public class Agente
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string continent { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }

    public Agente()
    {

    }
}
```

I need to group Objects of this class acording to its country, so i would have a list of ppl from Spain, another List of ppl from Italy.
After having those lists i need to display them on a windows phone app:

Country
Person 1
Person 2

Country
Person 3
Person 4

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to iterate through the persons list and then order them accrodingly by the country name..

```
List persons..
HashTable<List<Person>> countries=new HashTable();
foreach(person in persons){
 if(countries.contains(person.country)){
 countries.value.add(person);
}
else{
List<Person> per = new list();
per.add(person);
countries.add(person.country,per);
}
}
```

Comment: its complaining that it does not contain a definition for contains/value/add
when i do countries. intellsense only shows a couple of methods like ToString, am i missing a using ?

Comment: i just wrote the algo not the code.. you will need eradicate the error by yourself. those are just syntax errors or might be spelling mistakes. i have make some edits.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got them in some sort of sequence:

List items = ....

```
var byCountry = items.GroupBy( agente => agente.country);
```

Or to order them by country and then by id:

```
var byCountry = items.OrderByBy(agente => agente.country).ThenBy(agente => agente.id);
```

To render this in WPF you'll need some sort of collection. I'll assume you're using an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so on you view model make sure you've got an appropriate property, eg:

```
public ObservableCollection<Agente> Agents{get; private set;}
```

And initialize it like this:

```
var byCountry = items.OrderByBy(agente => agente.country).ThenBy(agente => agente.id);
this.Agents = new ObservableCollection<Agente>(byCountry);
```

Now, in your WPF declare your `ItemControl` to bind to this collection:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Agents" ItemsSource="{Binding Agents}>
```

NOTE: This assumes you've bound your your view model to the item that contains the `ItemsControl`.

Comment: I have a List<Agente> persons, but i can't do persons.GroupBy or persons.OrderByBy :\

Comment: Make sure you've got a `using System.Linq` in your file, and make sure you are refercing `System.Core.dll` in your references.

Comment: How would i pass the grouped information to XAML ? so i could display it like i mentioned in my inicial question.

Comment: One option would be to put it into an `ObservableCollection` afterwards.

Comment: hmm right now i have something like this on my xaml where the ItemsControl receives the list with all Agents http://paste2.org/vUExkXdx
I dont know how to put it into a ObservableCollection and then pass it to the XAML :\

Comment: could you help me out a bit more? :)

Comment: im a bit confused , im still quite new to WP8 development :( 
any chance you could provide a small working example ?

Comment: yes, but im getting some errors, using the OrderByBy ,my list doesnt seem to contain that method
i can do var byCountry = items.GroupBy( agente => agente.country); tho
but when i try to do this.Agents = new ObservableCollection<Agente>(byCountry); 
it says: Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Cartuxa.Agente>.ObservableCollection(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Cartuxa.Agente>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Well i managed to bind the ObservableCollection to the ItemsControl , but it still shows all of them without seperation, guess i need to work my XAML a bit more